# Dart2JS extended td not working in Firefox/IE

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer, dart-html, dart2js

I'm trying to build a simple CRUD-table by using polymer with dart.

The application consists of:

> -"crud-th" = TableRowElement which extends th
>   -"crud-tr" = TableRowElement which extends tr
>   -"crud-td" = TableCellElement which extends td

I'm calling my components this way:

```
<tr is="crud-th" template></tr>
<tr is="crud-tr" template></tr>
<td is="crud-td" template></td>
```

In Chrome/Dartium everything works fine but when trying to use this application
in Firefox/IE nothing gets displayed.
The Dart2JS compiler gives me following output:

> [Info from Dart2JS]: Took 0:00:05.747000 to compile
>   division|web/index.html_bootstrap.dart. Build completed successfully

When I'm not importing my crud-td component by commenting out

```
<link rel="import" href="crud-td.html">
```

the application works just fine.

The only solution for me right now is to stop using my extended-td component and instead
replace it with divs/spans.

Is there a solution to solve my problem or are there any future updates planed which will
solve this problem, so that for now I can continue using my extended-td component?

Comment: What is the purpose of the `template` attribute? With the information you provided it is hard to tell what might cause the problem but it is probably because there is something wrong/missing in your Polymer elements.

Comment: There is no real purpose for using template here. For me it seems like the problem is polymer itself and not my code. I can even create a new extended-td component which basicly does nothing, but as soon as i import it, nothing gets displayed again.

Comment: Can you please add the code that allows to reproduce the problem (Element HTML, Dart code, the code that adds the Element(s) to the DOM).

Comment: http://pastebin.com/qf2REpGv

thats code to reproduce the problem. Dartium shows "test" and Firefox shows nothing. Removing the Script tag in crud-td.html does fix the problem, but is not an option.

Comment: Looks fine so far but the `crud-td` has no `<content>` or `<shadow>` tag and therefore no position where the content/children can be placed.

Comment: Unfortunately neither <content> nor <shadow>  solve the problem.

Comment: Firefox Console shows this Error:
Error: index.html_bootstrap.dart.js: 2547

Line 2547 in the generated file is:
`this._queryParameters = parameter__queryParameters;`

Comment: I can reproduce that FireFox doesn't show anything when the element is imported but I have no idea what causes it. I think this is a bug. Can you please create a bug report at http://dartbug.com/new?

Comment: Seems that Firefox fails as soon as an element is imported that extends a DOM element. I haven't tried it with extending another element though. When crud-td is changed to not extend `TD` Firefox works fine.

Comment: We also use two extended tr elements, which do work fine if the crud-td import isnt there.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=21466&thanks=21466&ts=1414666881  Created the bug report